# Why is Power BI duplicating connection to server?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SER48.png)As I enter my server IP, port, user and password and try to connect, the following message appears to me "Connection option 'server' is duplicated". I tried cleanning permissions, updating both the plugin and software but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Could you please provide screen shots of your connection attempt?

Comment: Just uptaded with a screenshot